# CSS-переменные (кастомные свойства) в условии медиа-запросов. Подскажите правильный синтаксис

Tags: css

Суть того, что мне нужно понятна из кода, но этот синтаксис неверный, так не работает. Кто-нибудь знает как правильно?

```css
:root {
  --basewidth: 1200px;
}

@media (min-width: var(--basewidth)) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Существует черновик стандарта [Custom Media Queries](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-5/#custom-mq), позволяющий что-то подобное, но, насколько я знаю, это не реализовано ни в одном из браузеров. Придётся использовать пре- и/или постпроцессоры

Answer (score 2):

Если верить документации, то ваша задумка - неосуществима: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables

Можно использовать препроцессоры.

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries).

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае нет возможности использовать переменную для media-запросов.

Одним из способов достижения желаемого является использование пакета `npm postcss-media-variables`.

Или же использование препроцессора css.

Вы можете поступить следующим образом:

**CSS:**

```
:root {
  --base-color-red: red;
  --base-color-green: green;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--base-color-red);
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--base-color-green);
  }
}
```